# ORDER BY formula not working correctly

Tags: mysql

I've been searching for hours trying to figure out why ORDER BY would not work correctly on a formula:

```
SELECT *, 
    FORMAT(LowPriceCompetitor - (-(products.distPrice + 0.30) / ((Rates.rate + 0.02 + Rates.defaultMarkup) - 1)), 2) AS margin 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN Rates ON products.MasterCategoryID = Rates.categoryID 
ORDER BY margin
```

How can I get MySQL to correctly order the output of a formula? This *should* work!

Comment: It *does* work. The ORDER BY is ordering the rows in the specified sequence. As you found by consulting the MySQL documentation, the `FORMAT` function returns a character datatype. And the ORDER BY is operating on the character string. And what you want is to order on the numeric value. One quick way to convert a character datatype to numeric is to add a zero to it `'123.4'+0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised I could not find this here on SO. The solution is to use ROUND rather than FORMAT. i.e.

```
SELECT *, 
    ROUND(LowPriceCompetitor - (-(products.distPrice + 0.30) / ((Rates.rate + 0.02 + Rates.defaultMarkup) - 1)), 2) AS margin 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN Rates ON products.MasterCategoryID = Rates.categoryID 
ORDER BY margin
```

I should have been using ROUND to start with. FORMAT returns the result as a string...
I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: How did you do this?  Answered first then asked the question?  The Question and Answer have exactly the same time.

Comment: @vinodadhikary I started asking the question and in the process discovered the answer so I clicked the "Answer Your Own Question" button. SO apparently is set up for this exact situation.

Comment: @TimDuncklee, I see. I was just surprised, and had never seen before.  Thanks for getting back though.

Answer (score 3):

One quick way to sort strings as numeric values (for example, values returned by the `FORMAT()` function, or any other expression that returns a character datatype),

is to add zero to the expression. MySQL will perform an implicit conversion from character to numeric:

```
SELECT FORMAT(lpc - (-(p.dp + 0.30) / ((r.rate + 0.02 + r.dm) - 1)), 2) AS margin
  FROM t
  JOIN ... 
 ORDER BY margin+0
                ^^---- quick fix here is to add zero
```